# ip netns monitor not working in a script

Tags: networking, scripts, ip

I'm trying to use `ip netns monitor` in a script to react to the creation of new network namespaces, eg:

```
ip netns monitor | while read ACTION NETNS; do
 echo 'handling it!'
done
```

However I never see any output from `ip netns monitor` in this use case. Further experimenting reveals I never see any output from `ip netns monitor` if it is redirected or piped.

Here is a simple example of what does give the expected result:

```
$ ip netns monitor &
$ touch /var/run/netns/dummy ; sleep 2 ; rm /var/run/netns/dummy
add dummy
delete dummy
```

And here is another example of a usage that produces **zero** output:

```
$ ip netns monitor >/tmp/ip-netns-monitor.log 2>&1 &
$ ip netns monitor | cat &
$ touch /var/run/netns/dummy ; sleep 2 ; rm /var/run/netns/dummy
$ cat /tmp/ip-netns-monitor.log
# no results
```

I have tracked my version of `ip` back to this implementation of monitor:
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipnetns.c?id=3c61c01a666d9f4dbb871305ab6791e19ede7d4a#n462

I don't see anything obvious in the source that would cause behaviour to change based on where STDOUT is pointed - but I'm still new to all this.

Is there some way I should be using `ip netns monitor` so that it works in a script? Or should I be raising a bug somewhere?

If this is truly broken I can try a workaround with `inotifywait` instead.

My system:

```
$ ip -Version
ip utility, iproute2-ss131122
$ lsb_release --description
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
$ uname -rvm
3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64
```

---

### Update

I have run both interactive and redirected variants with `strace` and the results follow.

Method:

```
while true; do touch /var/run/netns/dummy ; sleep 2; rm /var/run/netns/dummy; sleep 2; done &
strace -ivy ip netns monitor
strace -ivy ip netns monitor | cat
```

Aside from some addresses and handles, strace shows the same initialisation for both. Where they vary is following the first read from inotify.

Interactive (ie without `| cat`) produces:

```
[00007ffe9274c767] inotify_init()       = 4
[00007ffe9274c737] inotify_add_watch(4<anon_inode:inotify>, "/var/run/netns", IN_CREATE|IN_DELETE) = 1
[00007ffe9273d3a0] read(4<anon_inode:inotify>, "\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0dummy\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096) = 32
[00007ffe9273cd84] fstat(1</dev/pts/0>, {st_dev=makedev(0, 12), st_ino=3, st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=5, st_blksize=1024, st_blocks=0, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), st_atime=2015/04/05-20:55:28, st_mtime=2015/04/05-20:55:36, st_ctime=2015/04/05-04:17:42}) = 0
[00007ffe9274655a] mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffe92e3a000
[00007ffe9273d400] write(1</dev/pts/0>, "add dummy\n", 10add dummy) = 10
[00007ffe9273d3a0] read(4<anon_inode:inotify>, "\1\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0dummy\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096) = 32
[00007ffe9273d400] write(1</dev/pts/0>, "delete dummy\n", 13delete dummy) = 13
```

Redirected (ie with `| cat`) produces:

```
[00007f607d90e767] inotify_init()       = 4
[00007f607d90e737] inotify_add_watch(4<anon_inode:inotify>, "/var/run/netns", IN_CREATE|IN_DELETE) = 1
[00007f607d8ff3a0] read(4<anon_inode:inotify>, "\1\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0dummy\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096) = 32
[00007f607d8fed84] fstat(1<pipe:[154785]>, {st_dev=makedev(0, 8), st_ino=154785, st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_size=0, st_atime=2015/04/05-21:04:54, st_mtime=2015/04/05-21:04:54, st_ctime=2015/04/05-21:04:54}) = 0
[00007f607d90855a] mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f607dffc000
[00007f607d8ff3a0] read(4<anon_inode:inotify>, "\1\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0dummy\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096) = 32
[00007f607d8ff3a0] read(4<anon_inode:inotify>, "\1\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\20\0\0\0dummy\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096) = 32
```

So, when redirected `fstat` has different results (expectedly) but `write` is never called. The results of `read` show that the notifications are coming through as expected. And `ip netns monitor` must be happy there is no error because it keeps looping.

Comment: You may get better help with this on [Unix.SE](//unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking a guess that this is possibly you hitting an issue where stdout on a pipe buffers at 4K. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25378 for some ideas on fixing it. To confirm this is your specific issue, try changing the name of your dummy file to something much larger, or call touch/rm multiple times, to generate enough output to hit the default buffer size.

Comment: Bingo! Longer file names, more events, and it eventually yields output when redirected. Cannot believe I haven't encountered this before. Using `stdbuf --output=L ip netns monitor | cat` solves it. Thanks.

Comment: I learned somthing today!  ;-)  Thanks! (Upvoted!)